# Canada storm reports

Tags: weather

I am looking for an equivalent of the SPC storm reports database they have in the US, but for Canada.

Is there a similar repository that would consist of observed severe weather (wind, hail, heavy rain, etc)? Weather stations just don't cut it, they are too sparse and don't record short-term severe weather very well.

Comment: When you say "too sparse", do you mean hourly observations don't suffice or their geographical density in "Canada" is too low? I also assume daily precipitation amounts or similar ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ data is insufficient?

Comment: I work at Quandl and noticed that we have some data on wind storms in Canada. Not sure if this kind of thing would help? See https://www.quandl.com/data/GEOCOMP?keyword=canada%20storm